# RxJS 5 firefox web extensions: TypeError: Math.random is not a function

Tags: rxjs5, firefox-addon-webextensions

RxJS 5 fails to work when injected as content script in firefox web extension and giving the following errors:
`TypeError: a.Math.random is not a function
TypeError: Rx.Subject is not a constructor`

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution, the issue occurred because in firefox content scripts window.Math is not defined instead it is defined globally as Math and not on window object. While RxJS 5 is looking for window.Math. So just before the RxJS library add the following line and it will work firefox.
`window.Math = Math`

Ref: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2446#issuecomment-286908341